# Low Baud Rate for USART3

Tags: arm, usart

On my stm32f103 I can not setup the baudrate 300 for USART3.
So, i'm doing it, but it receives nothing. Seems like it's not capable to receive data on 300 baud rate.
Is there posibility to use prescaller or so?

Comment: you read the st documentation for this part and that uart yes?   how are you setting the uart registers now?

Comment: can you show your configuration?